# Stream remote pi+rasp camera to another computer?

Tags: networking, raspicam, opencv, peripherals

Hi is it possible to stream the video feed from a pi camera (3 b+ model) across a LAN to another computer running Linux?

My idea is to see if pi can be used almost like an IP security camera where I can stream live video feed to a different PC on the LAN running Linux directly into OpenCV... No web browser connection, just live video stream from remote pi on LAN into another computer for running Linux OpenCV scripts python.

Hopefully that makes sense. Thank you for any tips-

Comment: Hey Henry – we tried a couple options for something like this, and everything out there was pretty clunky or required a lot of bandwidth. So, we built our own solution using a WebRTC library. It's a free, secure, and low-latency (but proprietary) way to get video from your RPi to any browser. Sounds like it might help your use case. Link is in my profile, if you want to give it a try! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

have you had a look at motioneyeos. It's a pre-built distro for doing just that. You get a variety of options for controling the camera framerate etc or you can choose to have it as a simple IP camera and view the feed as you wish on any computer.

Comment: Cool I haven’t heard of it.. is it a python package that I can pip for install on pi?

Comment: It's not a python package I'm afraid. It's a version of raspian you can flash onto your sd card. It essentially gives you a web interface to control some camera software called motion. You could install motion with apt on the pi and you should be able to set things up that way with scripts etc. Not looked at that myself to be honest because Motioneyeos let's you run motion really simply via a browser. https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos  You could set things up and control the camera directly with  a browser or set it up (via the browser) as an IP camera to access as you will

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is the RPi Web Cam Interface:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=63276

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. So in the link I think they are turning pi into a device that can stream motion jpeg to a separate server running apache PHP (right?) and I think then a user can dial up a web browser to the apache PHP server...

Comment: If they are NOT turning the pi into the webserver I think that would work.. I am hoping to stream pi video cam into OpenCV scripts running on a separate computer... And it seems like they are doing the same thing except for a web server

Comment: Any tips help.. The other posts above may work too for all  I know.. Thanks